# ASP.Net VB Check if datas exist in database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatareader

How do I check if data existing in the database or is NULL. I'm getting the following error *Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types* . Do I need to add IsDBNULL to the code?

```
SignedOn.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader("SignedOn")).ToShortDateString()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can check like below

```
If NOT IsDbNull(reader("SignedOn")) Then
   SignedOn.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader("SignedOn")).ToShortDateString()
End If
```

Edit based on comments:

- When you know the exact type of the column you can call method relevant to that type like `reader.GetDateTime`, `reader.GetString` etc
- After conversion if there is a possibility of result can be null then you better check for null before calling `ToShortDateString`
- You can use `DateTime.TryParse` method if you have store date time in varchar column

Comment: You should look at the .GetDateTime (.GetString, GetInt32 ) methods instead of using the "GetValue" (which is used as the default I believe).

Comment: @granadaCoder can you please add MSDN reference to this method? it will helpful for all. and normally [SqlDataReader.GetDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getdatetime.aspx) required to check for dbnull before calling.

Comment: The "check" is correct.  I'm not arguing that.  But I think you have a default to "GetValue" with this code : reader("SignedOn")

Comment: Here is my C# converted code to VB.NET that I think is correct.

Comment: @granadaCoder can you get date time by column name? and you assign date time to a string!

Comment: If Not (dataReader.IsDBNull(0)) Then
    dim d1 As DateTime = dataReader.GetDateTime(0)
End If

Comment: I don't know about the by "column name".  That will have to be attempted.  But the rule of thumb is that "GetString" "GetDateTime" are preferred over the "GetValue" when the type is known.

Comment: I always code to the interface, not the concrete.  My "converter" code uses IDataReader, not any of the concretes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29265/discussion-between-damith-and-granadacoder)